# Dataframe - find last time of the day, grouped by day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe with datetime and their date

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [['2021-01-01 10:10', '2021-01-01'],
                    ['2021-01-03 13:33', '2021-01-03'],
                    ['2021-01-03 14:44', '2021-01-03'],
                    ['2021-01-07 17:17', '2021-01-07'],
                    ['2021-01-07 07:07', '2021-01-07'],
                    ['2021-01-07 01:07', '2021-01-07'],
                    ['2021-01-09 09:09', '2021-01-09']],
                    columns=['datetime', 'date'])
```

I would like to create a new column containing the last datetime of each day.
I have something quite close, but the last datetime of the day is only filled on the last datetime of the day...
A weird NaT (Not a Time) is filled on all other cells.
Can you suggest something better?

```
df['eod']=df.groupby('date')['datetime'].tail(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `transform` which will return the result to every row in the group.

```
df['eod'] = df.groupby('date').transform('last')
```

Output

```
           datetime        date               eod
0  2021-01-01 10:10  2021-01-01  2021-01-01 10:10
1  2021-01-03 13:33  2021-01-03  2021-01-03 14:44
2  2021-01-03 14:44  2021-01-03  2021-01-03 14:44
3  2021-01-07 17:17  2021-01-07  2021-01-07 01:07
4  2021-01-07 07:07  2021-01-07  2021-01-07 01:07
5  2021-01-07 01:07  2021-01-07  2021-01-07 01:07
6  2021-01-09 09:09  2021-01-09  2021-01-09 09:09
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need another `date` column if the date part is coming from the datetime column. You can group by `dt.day` of the datetime column, then call last for the `datetime` value:

```py
>>> df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
>>> df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.day)['datetime'].last()

datetime
1   2021-01-01 10:10:00
3   2021-01-03 14:44:00
7   2021-01-07 01:07:00
9   2021-01-09 09:09:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```